# How to customize Firebase's project overview page

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform

[image: Firebase's project overview page]

This is my Firebase's project overview page. Now I can only switch the position of the Build section and the Analytics section.

Is there any way I can hide it? For example, hide the Build section (Hosting and Realtime Database) and show only Analytics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to hide panels from the home screen of the Firebase console. All you can do is re-order the panels, so that analytics shows on top.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Any idea why some project shows both Build and Analytics panels on the Home Screen but some shows only Build panel?

Comment: I think it depends on which products you use. I almost exclusive use Firebase's product to build apps, so only see that panel on my home screen. Apparently some of your projects use both build and analytics products, so you see both. Would that make sense?